# VLC convert blob to local mp4 - Reduce speed

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-conversion

I have m3u8 playlist file URL address (blob), and I want to download the video locally. To do so, I copy the URL to the VLC player (Media -> Open Network Stream -> Pase the URL -> select the "Video for MPEG4 1080p TV/device" profile -> Browse for the file destination -> and press Convert) to mp4 file.
The process works as expected, but the CPU reach to 100% about 90% of the time, which cause to my PC to shut down or to electric power break at my house.
Is there any way to make the process slower to reduce the CPU usage, but to keep the speed, frames, and the quality the same? 
(Already tried to add rate=0.5 and it made the video that has been converted to be slower.. this is not what I intended).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Video transcoding is a power-intensive task. It will always use all resources available.

I've found the simplest way to reduce the 'power consumption' is to run it in a VM & allow fewer cores.

Your computer ought to be able to run for hours at 100% CPU with no ill-effects other than you being almost unable to interact with it to do any thing else. That it doesn't would imply your cooling is insufficient.

For anything using as little mains power as a computer [compared to, say, a 3-bar electric fire] to trip RCDs or fuses would imply a serious issue with your mains power - which would be far beyond this stack's remit to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have some simple guide or reference how to create VM with fewer cores (Windows 10)?

Comment: Sorry, not to hand. Pick a VM, download the manual...